# MTensor from existing memory?

Tags: librarylink, c++

I am wondering whether it's possible to return a tensor from my C++ code using LibraryLink without copying the memory (because it's large).
So, instead of

```
libData->MTensor_new(..., &T0);
for(i...) libData->MTensor_setXXX(T0, ...);
MArgument_setMTensor(res, T0);
```

I would like to create the tensor from a block of memory,

```
libData->MTensor_new(..., buf, &T0);
// no copying needed
MArgument_setMTensor(res, T0);
```

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

PS: This would require Mathematica to release the memory eventually. In other binding frameworks, such as [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), this is achieved py passing a corresponding deleter function.

PPS: This would also require some information about internal layout of tensors in Mathematica. Again, no problem in the Python setting (with `numpy`) as one can specify strides. It also seems unlikely that Mathematica's internal tensor layout will change given the amount of collateral work that would cause.

PPPS: There is a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/converting-other-c-classes-to-mtensor-in-librarylink) from 2013. Perhaps something changed since then?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that this is possible.

What you *can* do is create a new MTensor with the desired amount of storage, and use that pre-allocated storage for the data structures of other libraries (if those other libraries allow this).

I have done something similar with the Armadillo library, which has the capability to wrap existing storage with its matrix type. A slight problem when using Armadillo with Mathematica is that it uses column-major storage, while Mathematica uses row-major storage. Thus when wrapping an `MTensor`'s data with Armadillo, you will get the transpose of the matrix.  I included some examples of this in [LTemplate](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate).

Comment: Your alternative might work for me, I'll give it a try once I get back to that code. Thank you.